# Beginner needs help with Self-Balancing-Robot build

Tags: imu

I'm looking for help on a 1st build self balancing robot, something that seemed pretty easy but not. I'm retired so have plenty of time but no real robot skills, electrical, mechanical yes.

I have been trying to get it working for weeks now, I have a chassis with two Nema17 motors, 65mm wheels, its 300mm high and the battery is at the top. I am using a Pi Pico as control with the MPU6050 IMU and two A4988 drives.

A friend on another group was building a game controller using the MPU6050 and has written a whole new driver for it that gives out filtered data - Kalman or Complimentary and it also does calibration etc.

I have tried my one code and failed but also today tried anothers code that was written specifically to show how easy it was - and it still failed for me.

This tells me maybe the motors are no good or the MPU is a bad choice, he used a BNO055 IMU.

The effect i get is that the bot will just jump about , even when static. Video - https://youtu.be/nNxNHaKN5w0

The code has a PID loop, makes little difference so far.

Is there maybe a recommended motor for these 'bots?

I am at a complete loss now as it seems nothing works, even code that is proven to work! It must be hardware???

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Dave, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: You start off mentioning a self-balancing robot, then you mention a friend that made a game controller, then you "tried anothers code" to show how easy "it" was and it failed for you. What is the code you were given? I would expect noise from any IMU, and it looks like the noise is driving the motors to oscillate some while the robot is upright. Compare the "jitter" there to the hand of someone [balancing a broom](https://recordsetter.com/world-record/balancing-broom-finger/38593) and you'll see that the jitter is not necessarily a sign of failure.

Comment: You haven't posted anything diagnostic yet - there's no code, no output plots, etc. The best I can tell you is that it looks like it's generally working correctly - there's jitter when the robot is upright, which again doesn't mean failure, and it looks like the wheels are turning in the correct direction to get the base under the top when it tilts. It looks slow to me, but this may be where your code is failing - if the other person had different motors, different wheels, etc. then their PID tuning would not be suitable for your device. Please post test data and we can help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks all, apologies for not asking in the correct form, i have not used this group before and it is not my usual style. I have number of things to check, my wheels may be too small, the steppers were not set for correct microstep, I am also using a different IMU than the build which has proven to work.

The jitter i see is reflected in the numbers i see from the IMU, i don't think its correct as the tilt angle reported can swing massively even when the unit is not moving, +/-10-20 degrees seems way too much for just noise or jitter.
I have a different IMU coming